# Integrating Elasticsearch with NodeJS with GraphQL

Tags: node.js, reactjs, elasticsearch, graphql

I would like to know if there are any examples on setting up graphQL for elasticsearch to run the search from NodeJs. I have elastic search working (tested search with the curl calls) and have built my nodejs/React JS app. I want to add search functionality here.
I would like to know if there are any samples on using graphQL with elasticsearch. I have been following the steps in this medium.com [article](https://medium.com/@andrewrymaruk/elasticsearch-graphql-react-node-express-how-cb2c2cc708f8). Would like to know if there are any examples for adding resolvers, I am assuming that is what is needed to actually run queries and retrieve results from graphQl.

Appreciate any input on this.
Thanks

Comment: I don't think you will actually want to make the search requests using GraphQL - it will mean routing requests through some other server/service. Rather make your search requests directly to the ElasticSearch instance

Comment: ... but if you want to hide BE details, don't want to update clients after changes ... just write an resolver ... get args, make request (async/await) adjust response shape to query/graphql requirements, return data